# Business reason for an Analyst

Tags: windows, events

One of our IT Security Analysts  is out on maternity leave

She had wiped the Windows Event Viewer logs off of a PC. Before we confront her we wanted to find out if there is any business reason for wiping these event logs.

I’m not an IT person so I’m not sure but we want to make sure that we give her a fair chance at explaining her actions when she returns to work.

Comment: How do you know, this personed wiped the event logs, is there an event of that happening?

Comment: Yes there is an event indicating she wiped the logs.

Comment: What was logged exactly?

Comment: Just to add. The *timing* of this - based off your question is fishy. Be *very* careful about what you do - if you're trying to fire someone on maternity leave and are trying to find reasons after the fact, its pretty illegal in many jurisdictions.

Answer (score 5):

> She had wiped the Windows Event Viewer logs off of a PC.

In a typical corporate setup, the event logs are archived by size, which creates an archive file.  So before you confront somebody, about something you admit you know very little about, you might want to check the configuration of the machine.  *This same functionality can rotate logs, so an archive is NOT created, which means older events would eventually be overwritten by more recent activity.*

> I’m not an IT person so I’m not sure but we want to make sure that we give her a fair chance at explaining her actions when she returns to work.

Based on this statement alone, you shouldn't confront the security analyst in question, because it appears you are unfamiliar with how the system is actually configured.  As an Administrator myself, If somebody came to me who in their own words, describe themselves as "not an IT person" I would go to their manager immediately and make sure they are disciplined.

If another Administrator came to me, I would explain my actions and would move on with my life.  As an Administrator, there are numerous situations, where cleaning up the events that have been logged would be acceptable behavior.

Comment: @JavaScripter007 - No; There are far to many to provide a list, the situations I can think of, would be far specific to the network I am an Administrator of.  The list wouldn’t be helpful to anyone outside of my organization.  I won’t speculate what reasons this Administrator had to clear the events in question.

Comment: You can't even provide 1 or 2 reasons? @Ramhound

Comment: @JavaScripter007 The event log was corrupt and until I cleared it no more events would get logged.

Comment: @JavaScripter007 - Can I provide 1 or 2 reasons, I absolutely could provide them.  I have answered your question, as it’s written, and won’t be providing those reasons.  I also won’t be returning to this question.

Answer (score -2):

A number of different 'cleaning' apps suggest deleting them to save space. She might have installed one of those to resolve a different issue, and not understood the implications of letting such an app clean away the logs.

Comment: That is gross speculation. The questioner admits to knowing very little about IT so it's highly unlikely that he's done an research or investigation to determine if anyone wiped the logs at all or if it was a system setting such as rotating the logs.